# libxml2 taking huge memory(like 8GB for 600MB doc) for parsing

Tags: libxml2

I am using libxml2 for parsing xml doc and i see using valgrind that xmlParseFile takes like 8GB for parsing 600MB file. i found on the libxml2 site that it usually takes 4 times the xml doc size but for me it takes lot more than that.
Can anyone point what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the structure of the document, but a factor of 10-20 is nothing unusual. The "4 times" quote probably refers to 32-bit systems. On a 64-bit system, the overhead is larger, typically about 120-150 bytes for every element and attribute, in addition to the actual character data.

For data this large, XML is often the wrong choice. But using one of libxml2's streaming parser interfaces (SAX or *xmlreader*), you should be able parse such documents with much lower memory overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I tried using xmlReadfile with XML_PARSE_COMPACT option and got the usage down to 6.5GB, but that is quite huge too for my application